# How can I get table of contents entries to wrap instead of clip on my Kindle device?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

The table of contents entries on my Kindle device are truncated after about 25 characters. This prevents me from seeing the full entry.

Worse still, when the entry has a long prefix like "Chapter Seventeen", for example, you might only see a very small part of the chapter title.

Here's an illustration of the problem:

[image: Kindle table on contents on device vs Mac app]

This is very frustrating. You can't get a quick overview of the book by reading the ToC. It's also hard to find previous sections which you might like to refer back to.

Furthermore, the ToC in the Kindle app for Mac shows subchapters, whereas the device doesn't. Is there a way to fix that?